# setting matplotlib xlimits (with Pandas DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis

I have the following code that produces a plot

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(20,2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,15))
fs = 13
min_factor = 1.2
max_factor = 4.0
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:8,0])
title = 'e1 on Object a'
plt.title('Bias vs Separation For ' + title,fontsize=fs)
plt.xlabel('Separation (Arcsec)',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylabel('Residual',fontsize=fs)
plt.ylim([min_factor*mi,max_factor*ma])
means_e1_a.T.plot(ax=ax,style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'],yerr=s_means_e1_a.T)
```

[image]

Now I simply want my x axis to have a margin so I can see the error bars on the last points. Now if I do something like:

```
means_e1_a.T.plot(ax=ax,style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'],yerr=s_means_e1_a.T,
                  xlim=(0.8,2.2))
```

it returns

[image]

What do I have to do to get 0.8 and 2.2 with the proper labelings. Note, I should have a data point with error bars on the following x points:

```
 [1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0]
```

Comment: Hi @alvarezcl, does my below answer help address your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `plot` is autoscaling the `xlim`s:

```
plt.ylim([min_factor*mi,max_factor*ma])
plt.xlim(0.8, 2.2)
means_e1_a.T.plot(ax=ax, style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'], yerr=s_means_e1_a.T)
print plt.xlim()
> (1.2, 2.0) # not what we told it to do!
```

Set the `xlim`s *after* calling `plot`:

```
means_e1_a.T.plot(ax=ax, style=['k--o','b--o','g--o'], yerr=s_means_e1_a.T)
plt.ylim([min_factor*mi,max_factor*ma])
plt.xlim(0.8, 2.2)
print plt.xlim()
> (0.8, 2.2) # much better :)
```

(Alternatively, you could also turn autoscale off with `ax.autoscale(False)`.)

I would be happy with this answer, except for the fact that if I try the second thing you have above (passing `xlim` as an argument to `plot`), it works properly for me (though apparently not for you). So unfortunately I can't reproduce your problem for the second part, but if you can include a complete set of code with sample data, etc., I'll try to reproduce it again.